Julia 2D integration
I am trying to integrate in Julia:

I have tried both QuadGK and Cubature with no success. This was my attempt with Cubature:
function h_10(K, i)
  function integrand(x, v)
    return f_X_opt(K, i, x) * g_V_sub(K, i, v)
  end
  result, _ = hcubature(x->integrand.(x[1],x[2]),[-Inf,-Inf], [Inf, Inf])
  return 1 - result
end
res = h_10(K, i)
print(res)

But when I run this code my result is NaN... I assume I am incorrectly defining the integral limits but after some research I am unclear on how to define the integral limits with a variable?
Update: I believe I've made some progress by seeing that a change of variables is needed in order to integrate over infinite integrals.. My revised code is now:
transform(t)= t/(1-(t)^2)
dtransform(t)= (1+ t^2)/(1-t^2)^2
function h_10(K, i)
  function integrand(x, v)
    return f_X_opt(K, i, transform(x)) * g_V_sub(K, i, transform(v))* dtransform(x)* dtransform(v)
  end
  result, _ = hcubature(x->integrand.(x[1],x[2]),[-1,-1], [1, 1])
  return 1 - result
end
res = h_10(K, i)
print(res)

However, I now get an incorrect value. I believe that this is once again due to the limits of the integral because I am not passing x into the upper limit of the inner integral.

Try with a simpler integrand to see if it is f_X_opt or g_V_sub's fault. NaN is a special value for floating point numbers which tends to be very contagious, so any calculation yielding NaN can cause the final result to be NaN.

I've tested both f_X_opt and g_V_sub and they work as expected.

What happens withtransform if x or v are one?

I'm unclear on how it works but this was the solution posted here under the infinite integrals section: link

When changing/transforming the variables (as you have done), the integrand needs to be multiplied by the absolute of the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation.

Another "administrative" point - the original question was regarding a NaN problem, and now it migrated to a different problem (the missing Jacobian problem), it ought to have been a new question, otherwise this can go on and on.

The original question was always regarding the use of Cubature and how to handle the limits of integration.. the fact that my original attempt resulted in NaN was beside the point. I included an update to my original question because I discovered new information regarding the change of variables that I thought may be helpful for those assisting with my original question. But thank you for your input.

There seems to be something wrong with f_X_opt or g_V_sub. The integral in the question is separable. Which means you can calculate a single integral for f and for g separately - this would be faster and more accurate.
Because both of them are likely distribution functions, a simple check is to see whether hcubature(x->f_X_opt(K, i, transform(x[1])*dtransform(x[1]), -1, 1) equals 1.0 (for any K and i used). If it isn't, something is wrong with the probability distribution. The same for g.
